# How to exclude keyword in brackets in python without using regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file I am reading and separating by line and want to print only sentences that have the keyword: 'Cat' in them. The file though, contains asides that are formatted in braces, ex. {Once Cat enters the room}

Full text: 
CAT. 
{Cat enters the room.} Dog, what are you doing here?

DOG. 
What does it look like I'm doing Cat? I'm watching Cops.

CAT. 
I didn't know that you were that big of a fan Dog! What city does this one take place in?

DOG. 
{He turns his chair to Cat.} Take a guess Cat!

CAT. 
I don't know! I'm just trying to make conversation.

I'm able to print the lines that contain the keyword I'm looking for, but when I do print, it also outputs the brace lines as well. I've tried adding more than one separators, but I get an error every time I try.

```
for i in catDog.split('\n'):
    if str('Cat')in i:
        print(i)
```

I expect the output: 
What does it look like I'm doing Cat? 
Take a guess Cat!

Instead I get: 
[Cat enters the room.] 
What does it look like I'm doing Cat? 
[He turns his chair to Cat.] 
Take a guess Cat!

I don't want anyone to write the code for me; moreso point me in the right direction.

Comment: The code is doing what you are telling it to do. In each of those sentences the word Cat is that line so the code will return the word cat. Is there more we can query the lines on?

Comment: By "keyword", do you  mean `cat` in all capital letters, or does it also have to start the line as well?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Right, is it possible to exclude the lines that have braces {} ?

Comment: @chepner the keyword being 'Cat' , case sensitive of course. I just re-formatted the code as well for easier understanding

Comment: If the { are strings you can use something like if "{" not in i. but without seeing the actual representation of the lines its hard to tell

Answer (score 1):

Given a line like:

```
 {Cat enters the room.} Dog, what are you doing here?
```

It's unclear from your question whether (a) that line should match and (b) if it matches, whether we should only print the content outside of the `{...}` section.  Assuming yes in both of those cases, you could do something like:

```
for i in catDog.split('\n'):
    if str('Cat') in i:
        parts = i.split('}', 1)
        print(parts[1 if len(parts) > 1 else 0])
```

Which would get you:

```
 Dog, what are you doing here?
What does it look like I'm doing Cat? I'm watching Cops.
 Take a guess Cat!
```

If you want to ignore matches in the initial `{...}` section, then you could write:

```
for i in catDog.split('\n'):
    parts = i.split('}', 1)
    if str('Cat') in parts[-1]:
        print(parts[1 if len(parts) > 1 else 0])
```

Which gets you:

```
What does it look like I'm doing Cat? I'm watching Cops.
 Take a guess Cat!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what types of brackets/braces are containing your asides, you remove that part of the string before looking for cat.

```py
if i.startswith('{'):
  i = i[i.index("}") + 1:]

if str("Cat") in i:  
  print(i)
```

Comment: but it's not possible to get the exact exact position of the ending brace }

Comment: ```index('}')``` provides that location

Comment: would you be able to explain the line: i = i[i.index("}") + 1:]          I'm having difficulty understanding how to interpret that..

Comment: That line assigns the substring of i from the location of ```"}" + 1``` to its end back to the variable i. ```somestring[startIndex:endIndex]``` returns a sub-string starting from the ```startIndex``` and ending at ```endIndex - 1```. Leaving ```startIndex``` out means start from the beginning, leaving ```endIndex``` out means all the way to the end. ```index('}')``` returns the index of the first match it finds.